# Run eJabberd register user command as root/normal user

Tags: php, ubuntu, ejabberd

I have installed the **eJabberd** and its working fine. Now I have to integrate the registration and other functionality with **PHP** code.

I am trying to run following script to register user using PHP code :

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '-1');

$username   = 'user1';
$password   = '123456';
$node       = 'localhost';

exec('echo <password> | sudo -u root -S ejabberdctl register '.$username.' '.$node.' '.$password.' 2>&1',$output,$status);

if($output == 0)
{
    echo "User created successfully.";
}
else
{
    // Failure, $output has the details
    echo '<pre>';
    foreach($output as $o)
    {
        echo $o."\n";
    }
    echo '</pre>';
}
?>
```

But its giving me following error :

```
[sudo] password for www-data: Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for www-data:
sudo: 1 incorrect password attempt
```

Is there any other way to run **eJabberd** commands using **PHP** ?

Any reference will be very helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What user is PHP running as? In other words, are you running PHP from cmd line as the current user or via a webserver?

Comment: I am running PHP via webserver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You web service will be running as user `www-data` in Ubuntu. You can allow this run run specific commands as root using /etc/sudoers.

Add this line to your sudoers.

```
www-data  ALL = NOPASSWD: /[FULL PATH TO]ejabberdctl
```

Replace [FULL PATH TO] with the full path to that script.

What this will do is say that the user `www-data` can run the script at that location as `root`.  It also says no password is required.

Obviously this has some security considerations - ensure that you trust the script and that it cannot be replaced by other malicious code.

An alternative solution would be to make ejabberdctl always run as root.  To to that use this on the executable.

```
chmod +s ejabberdctl
```

Once again this may have implications as now any user on your system can use that command. You have to think through the difference scenarios and choose which introduces the least risk for your given circumstances.

Comment: facing same issue with second option,  but first option is working for me. So thanks.

Comment: Interesting feedback - I will try that myself sometime and figure it out. Thanks

Comment: the solution worked on the my local system but facing problem on server, I posted new question here : [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33915005/host-key-verification-failed-using-php-script-centos](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33915005/host-key-verification-failed-using-php-script-centos). Please give some suggestions, Thanks.