# "Host key verification failed" using PHP Script - CentOS

Tags: linux, ssh, centos, ejabberd

I am trying to create **eJabberd** users using **PHP** script.

The following script is working perfectly on my local system(Ubuntu 14.04) :

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '-1');

$username   = 'userx1';
$password   = '123456';
$node       = 'localhost';

exec('ssh -t -t <hostname> ejabberdctl register '.$username.' '.$node.' '.$password.' 2>&1', $output, $status);

if($output == 0)
{
    echo "User created successfully.";
}
else
{
    // Failure, $output has the details
    echo '<pre>';
    foreach($output as $o)
    {
        echo $o."\n";
    }
    echo '</pre>';
}
```

But when I am trying to run on the server(CentOS).
Its giving me following error :

```
Host key verification failed.
```

I tried some solutions like :

https://askubuntu.com/questions/45679/ssh-connection-problem-with-host-key-verification-failed-error

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IJj0uD7EgGk

but no success.

Any reference will be very helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That askubuntu.com answer looks pretty comprehensive to me. Maybe you could explain in more detail how you tried to follow those suggestions, and what happened.

Comment: @Kenster I follow the command as per the answer on the AskUbuntu. But when running the PHP script the output was same. I also followed this video tutorial : [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IJj0uD7EgGk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IJj0uD7EgGk) but no success. I am not able to trace the issue.

Comment: What happens if you try to manually run the ssh command, do you get the same error?

Comment: No, I am getting error only when running through PHP script.

Answer (score 0):

Found A better way to crate user to `eJabberd` server.

**mod_rest :**
https://github.com/processone/ejabberd-contrib/tree/master/mod_rest

Provides you to make REST calls to the server.